# Cutkontur 4 contour cutting in data is applied as a surface?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, path, cutter

I have to send for printing letters which will be processed by cutter.The company send me yesterday an email saying I had open paths, I tripled checked my file in illustrator indeed was 2 paths open now all paths are closed. But I got this email saying "- Unfortunately, the Cutkontur for contour cutting in your data is applied as a surface. Please create a single continuous closed factorized contour path. " is all vectors in in my file what do they mean ? I would call them but they don't speak English and i don't speak german!

Comment: Hire a translator.

Comment: have you searched around? I never worked with cutkontur but from a quick search it seems it needs some special setup

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it means the printer wants you to set up the file in some way that will allow their cutter software to recognise the path for cutting.

These settings often include specifications such as putting the cutter path on its own layer above your artwork, with a specific CMYK colour stroke applied, and the colour swatch renamed to "CutContour" or a name their cutter software will recognise.

As to the specific CMYK colour, or name of the swatch required, I think your are going to have to ask them. I'm serious and not joking - either hire a translator, or use a printer who has at least one employee who speaks English, or learn German!

I've had to hire human translators several times for print related work, it's not uncommon.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help !  they needed 1 continuous line !

Answer (score 0):

"Single continuous closed factorized contour path" I guess "factorized" is a wrong translation of "vectorized".

There's a [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D94H5xiOArc) in which you do not need to know German to understand what they ask you.

They use this as a starting design:

[image]

They make several steps to come up with a unified sticker-type design:

- Get rid of inner shapes
- Adding strokes to unify separated shapes (the characters)
- Integrate all the objects
- And make a continuous simple path of the entire design as a sticker

[image: CutKontour01]

[image: CutKontour02]

Making this depends on the complexity of your design. There are many nice tutorials on internet searching *How to Create a Sticker Cut Line in Illustrator*

Like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jaT8Dyodzg0

Comment: Thank you! they needed 1 continuous line  just like the one above !

Comment: @BluePars If this is the answer that you needed, then you should choose it as best answer.